# R error subsetting data.frame when using [[

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

For a data frame (data) which has one columns as sulfate,
What is a difference between `data[["sulfate"]]` and `data[[colnames(data)=="sulfate"]]`?

`data["sulfate']` and `data[colnames(data)=="sulfate"]` yields same valued result and have data frame class but `data[["sulfate"]]` results into a numeric vector in my case but `data[[colnames(data)=="sulfate"]]` turns out to be an error. Why?

[image: Picture showing the error.]

Comment: The latter is an error.

Comment: Its an error but data["sulfate"] and data[colnames(data)=="sulfate"] gives the same output of a dataframe with similar values but when we try to convert it in numeric vector by using [[colnames(data)="sulfate"]] it turns out to be an error.Why?

Comment: The index arguemnt of [[ must be a scalar, not a logical vector.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck `[[` accepts vectors, I don't think that's the issue in this case. The issue is that first FALSE is turned to numeric 0 and the error is "attempt to select less than one element".

Comment: @Karolis, No.  It only accepts vectors if the object argument is a nested list.  For example, `list(1, list(2, 3))[[c(2, 1)]]` works.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck `iris[[c(1,2)]]` will thrown no error. And if we expand the subsetting vector `iris[[c(1,2,3)]]` it throws a different error compared to `iris[[colnames(iris)=="Species"]]` which suggests that the error is not because the subsetting is being done with a vector instead of a single number.

Comment: A data frame is a list and there are no cases where the vector argument can be logical.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck you can check `iris[[colnames(iris)=="Sepal.Length"]]` and `iris[[colnames(iris)=="Species"]]` and confirm that this gives different error messages. Which again shows that the issue is because of `0` entries in the subset vector, not because it's logical or because it has multiple elements. Furthermore `iris[[c(TRUE,TRUE)]]` will work.

Comment: You are changing the problem.  The data frame in the question has a "sulfate" column.  Furthermore if there are multiple errors in an expression you won't necessarily get a message for all of them. More likely you only get a mesasge for one of them but that does not mean that that is the reason.  Furthermore, iris[[c(TRUE, TRUE)]] gets coerced to iris[[c(1,1)]]. It is not treated as a logical vector.

Comment: About the coercion to numeric - yes! But that's exactly my point. The original comment to which I replied was "argument ... must be a scalar, not a logical vector". All I am arguing with is that the argument to `[[` can be both logical and a vector. The issue is that it doesn't make sense for the OPs data when turned to numeric.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius I think, we can't pass a logical vector in [[ because all possible combinations are c(T,T) ,c(T,F),C(F,T),C(F,F) in first case we will get no error but in second case we will be stopped at level 2 because it encounters 0 and throws error ,and in rest of both subsetting is done on 0 entries. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ShivamSingh you definitely should not be passing logical vector to `[[`. And in an ideal world it would stop you from doing this as it's almost never a desired way to subset something. All I am saying is that error you are getting currently is not because it's a logical vector per se - as there are situations where logical vector doesn't produce any error. The error you get is because the "FALSE" is turned to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - here are some ways to achieve what you are trying to achieve:

```
data$sulfate

getElement(data, "sulfate")
```

Next a short explanation why `data[[colnames(data)=="sulfate"]]` does not work.

1) The expression within `[[` is `colnames(data)=="sulfate"` which is a logical vector.

2) Function `[[` accepts a single element (because it's used to select a single element) or a numeric vector in which case it is used to select elements of a nested list. For example:

```
a <- list(list(2,3), list(3,4))
> a[[c(2,1)]]
[1] 3
```

The help page **help(`[[`)** will have more information about how it works.

3) The `data.frame` object in R is a list, you can confirm this by doing `is.list(data)`. So the function `[[` works the same way.

Now what happens when you pass it a vector instead of a single number - it gets turned into a numeric representation of 0s and 1s. For example inspect `as.numeric(colnames(data)=="sulfate"))`.

Then the subsetting `[[` encounters 0 entries and when you try to subset using a 0 it throws an error that you are attempting to select less than one element.

```
data[[0]]
```

Notice that the error is the same as when doing `data[[colnames(data)=="sulfate"]]`